# Rails: Most efficient way to check if a new record already exists in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Lets say I have a model `Product`.

Once in a while I get a file containing new products, the issue is that some of them may already have been entered into the DB.

The data doesn't contain any unique key and the can come structured differently with different fields. What I can do is select from the DB according to all the data I have and if a product is found, not to save the one from the file.

```
Product.where(:name => p.name, :desc => p.desc, :source => "some source", [more fields])
```

**So my question is if there is a better rails way to check if the record already exists?**

Inserting to fail on some unique key, isn't such a good idea IMO but can work too.

Comment: Adding an `Unique key` to the table is always an efficient and most recommended way.And it also makes your life easier.Believe me.

Comment: How else are you going to know if a record exists other than looking it up first? Is there something wrong with this approach? Is it taking too long? Is the uniqueness problem the one you're trying to solve, or are you trying to address a slowness/design issue? Do your products not have UPCs or something else that designates them as unique?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `rails` word. My question if there is a better rails way to check this as selecting or inserting are probably the only conceptual ways to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [exist?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html) function like this :

```
if Product.where(:name => p.name, :desc => p.desc, :source => "some source", [more fields])
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

You can also use the [find_or_create_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) if your goal is to create a new record if it does not exist like this :

```
Product.find_or_create_by(:name => p.name, :desc => p.desc, :source => "some source", [more fields])
```

Comment: `find_or_create_by` is a way to go here.

Comment: Following your advice, I used `find_or_initialize_by` as I didn't want the record to be created right away. Thanks!